Find the area of the plane region bounded by the curves $2y=4x-x^2$ and $2y+3x=6$.
The problem:
Find the area of the plane region bounded by the curves $2y=4x-x^2$ and $2y+3x=6$.
The solution:
$\frac{125}{12}$ square units
What I have tried:
I begin by rewriting the equations.
$$2y=4x-x^2 \iff y=\frac{4x-x^2}{2}$$
$$2y+3x=6 \iff y=\frac{6-3x}{2}$$
I look for the points of intersection by setting the equations equal to one another.
$$\frac{4x-x^2}{2}=\frac{6-3x}{2} \iff (x-1)(x-6)=0$$
I determine which curve is above by evaluating both functions at an $x$ value within the domain $[1,6]$, f.ex. $x=3$.
$$y_{parabola}=\frac{4 \cdot 3 - 3^2}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$y_{line}=\frac{6-3 \cdot 3}{2}=-\frac{3}{2}$$
Since $\frac{3}{2} \gt -\frac{3}{2}$, the parabola is above the line.
The area is:
$$A = \int_1^6 \left[\frac{4x - x^2}{2} - \frac{6 - 3x}{2}\right] \, dx = \int_1^6 \frac{-x^2 + 7x - 6}{2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left( \frac{-6^3}{3} + \frac{7(6^2)}{2} - 6(6) \right) - \left( \frac{-1^3}{3} + \frac{7(1^2)}{2} - 6(1) \right) \right]=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{59}{3} = \frac{59}{6}$$
My questions:
Why am I not getting the correct area? Am I doing something wrong or is my book wrong?

seems like there is an arithmetic mistake in the final step.

You divided by $2$ twice when simplifying the integrand.

The big square brackets in your last line evaluate to $\frac{125}{6}$, not $\frac{59}{3}$. Then, when you multiply by $\frac12$, you get the given answer of $\frac{125}{12}$.

you mean the given answer of $\frac{125}{12}$

Yes @J.W.Tanner. Thanks. Fixed.
